# Strategy for quick icon generation for labview?

Tags: labview

Labview programs become difficult to maintain when block diagrams get too big.

Usage of subvis is recommended to avoid this.

By default, every subvi's icon looks the same, except for a number.

I find that the time needed to creating meaningful icons for most subvis exceeds the coding time by far. Even if using existing images instead of that integrated icon editor - first find a suitable one, then I usually have to scale and adapt it.

Even when settling on using just text in the end, the time needed for icon creation still exceeds the time for programming the vi.

I can see the following strategies to avoid wasting time with icon design:

- All in one large vi
- Not creating relatively simple subvis with less than approx 20 blocks (adjust number with experience)
- Just have the default icon everywhere

I do not like any of these. They do not help with maintainability.

It seems there is a trade-off between maintainability and time required for icon design.

How do people with labview experience solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LabVIEW help includes some [simple instructions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvhowto/creating_vi_icon/) for creating an icon template and then using that template to create an icon for each new VI you create. I really don't see why either of those steps should take you more than about fifteen seconds!

There's certainly no need to be an artist, or take too much trouble over it, to create a VI icon: all that really matters is that each VI icon is:

- identifiable as part of your application - this is why to use a template; and
- distinguishable from the other VI icons in your application - you can easily do this with a couple of words of text or a glyph from the included set, even if you choose the latter at random.

Comment: the problem is that icons are too small. You can't write much, and ofter you have to squeeze text so much that you just have to rely on subvi name: you drop the subVI, then right click->visible item->label.
It's impossible to picture a concept inside the icon.
If you use template, you have even less space, because most of the time you use the top pixels for a common title for the vilib to apply to all members.

Comment: @YagamiLight how many VIs do you have in an application, where this starts to become a problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many. it's always a problem. Icons are just too small. After 10+ years on LV I found the real problem: the CEO. NI CEO was like 70 years old and just retired last june. That is insane. In fact there is ZERO innovationin LV since 2010. Every year they add up so few things that staying up SSP is just a rippoff. This year I got 2016 and turned off my SSP and I won't pay untile 2020. It's so stale that it makes me laugh. This is the result of having a 70yo CEO that has the mind stuck in the 90s.

Comment: you just can't write "shutdown" in a single line. LOL. There is simple not space for a usable human usability

Answer (score 3):

The right way to create VIs anyway.

I would suggest adding all VIs into a single library then change the icon of the lib to one you like and click the Apply Icon To VIs. This will add the Library Icon to all library functions like a template.

Then you can use VI scripting to programmatically add text on VI icon (For ex. VI Name): http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209110

I suggest you take a look on this: https://lavag.org/files/file/100-mark-ballas-icon-editor-v24-lv2010/

It will show you how you can write text on a VI's icon programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Install [GOOP Development suite](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209038):

In the menu, click:

> Tools->GOOP->Create VI Icon...

Then click 'accept'.  95% of the time, this is appropriate.
The other 5% of the time is used to set up headers based on

> library/class/folder

Then GDS offers to update the headers for the other member VI's.